# Android - How to show Toast on ConnectionTimeout

Tags: java, android, exception, android-asynctask, toast

I have the following problem: My app uses a function which executes all HTTP calls. As a quick fix I'd like to show the user a toast message whenever there is an `ConnectionTimeout`.

The problem is that this executeHttp() is called from several `AsyncTasks` and I can't figure out how to get the required `context`.

I read something about `runOnUiThread` but this also didn't seem to work for me...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Update:**

I'd like to have a solution which I can use in my `executeHttp()` function because else I have do add this code in 100 different places... Is this possible?

Comment: what does "but this also didn't seem to work for me" mean?

Comment: YOu will get timeout response as result, so why not u are usiing that result

Comment: in connectiontimeoutexception, return variable with some value. and then check in response. if you get value of timeoutexception then show toast.

Comment: If you mean, that you want to do something in async task on main ui thread, than you should use AyncTask's onProgressUpdate/onPostExecute for example. These methods are executed on main ui thread.

Comment: @PankajKumar: How do you want to show this result?

Comment: I don't want to show the result :D you want it :D read what you got from response and show in toast...

Comment: thats my problem... I can't show the toast in my function :)

Comment: post Your function code and how You call it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, implement a Method to show a Toast to your activity:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
// some stuff

    public void showToast(String text, int duration) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

The let your AsyncTask hold a reference to the activty which can then be called in the onProgressUpdate Method:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

    MyActivity activity;

    public MyAsyncTask(MyActivity a)
        this.activity = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {       
            // do your stuff here

        } catch (ConnectionTimeoutException e) {
            publishProgress("timeout");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        if(values[0].equals("timeout")
            activity.showToast("Ups, we have a timeout!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); }
        }
    }
}
```

## EDIT ------------

If you want it in your executeHttp() method, you have to pass the Context to it in order to show a Toast:

```
public ReturnValue executeHttp(Context context) {
    try {
        // ...
    } catch(ConnectionTimeoutException e) {
        Toast t = Toast.makeToast(context, message, duration);
        t.show();
    }
}
```

summary: no available context -> no toast

Comment: thanks for your post. do you think it works passing the context via the asynctask to the toast?

Comment: see my edit. it should work as Taost only needs that (also it its not good coding style)